# Batch file to open excel works on sql server agent , but sql server job never completes and goes in a loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a batch file to open a spreasheet and run the auto open macro. This work . Putting the batch file on a sql server agent job, again it works but the job never seems to end . Any ideas why ?

Code for batch file

call C:\Imports\Account.xlsb
exit

code for sql server agent

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c  "C:\Imports\Test\OpenExcelFile.bat"

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the Excel process show in task manager after a few minutes of being run? Perhaps the process is exiting but Agent isn't "hearing" the termination.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to run cmd.exe to run a batch file.  You should only need to specify the file name name in quotes while using an "Operating system (CmdExec) job step.  The step should use the following code:

```
"C:\Imports\Test\OpenExcelFile.bat"
```

If this doesn't work, then try running the batch file from the xp_cmdshell stored procedure.  Here's the code you would need to execute:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\Imports\Test\OpenExcelFile.bat';
GO
```

This could be called by a Transact-SQL script (T-SQL) job step.

Are you calling this in a SSIS package?  The post was tagged as SSIS, but you never mentioned in the post that you tried to call this from a SSIS package.  If this is a SSIS package, then are you able to run the SSIS package successfully in BIDS?  If you are running this from BIDS, then you shouldn't need to call the cmd.exe file.  There is an Execute Process Control Flow task that you could use that does not require running a batch file from cmd.exe.  If you are not using a SSIS package, then can you remove the SSIS tag?

Comment: Was not able to run this step in SSIS so took it out and started trying it as a seperate job step. In SSIS , I had this step as a window scheduler task which open the excel file and then that runs the auto open macro, howvever this not working on sql server agent. Will try your suggestion tonight or tommorrow and come back with feedback. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Tried suggestion 1 and the same behaviour , it just runs and runs and does not seems to stop . Been 5 minutes so far .

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to run a client-side command server-side.  Take a look at this: http://jessicammoss.blogspot.com/2008/10/manipulating-excel-spreadsheets-in-ssis.html.  You may be able to open the spreadsheet via a script task and run whatever it needs to run.

Comment: I checked a few more sites and they say you can open an Excel file and execute a macro through a batch file with the Execute Process command.  They also indicate you should change the SuccessValue to 1 as well.  Here's one post that mentioned this solution.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/1ad1980f-cf4c-490b-ad9d-f8b4ea2425d8.

Comment: Below is an example of using the ActiveX Control Flow task to open an Excel spreadsheet which may work.

Function Main()
Dim Excel_app
Dim ExcelCode
Set Excel_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set ExcelCode = Excel_app.workbooks.open("\\mrtb03.dr.snfores.com\tb\prodSCD\XXX\INFXXSUS\XXX_CVR_CS\Template\VBACode.xls")
Excel_app.Run "Start"
ExcelCode.Close
Excel_app.Quit
Set Excel_app = Nothing
Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success
End Function